# Java Lambda. This method must return a result of type ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, functional-interface

I have a map of employee name and employee salary and I want to return a list of employees' names whose salary is less than or equal to the salary passed as an argument using lambda and functional interface. This is what I am doing but it is showing me an error this method should return a result of the type list.

```
public static EmployeeAudit findEmployee() {
       return salary ->  
            employeeMap.entrySet()
                       .stream()
                       .filter(s -> s.getValue() <= salary)
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

```
public interface EmployeeAudit {
    ArrayList<String> fetchEmployeeDetails (double salary);
}
```

Comment: What is `employeeMap`? Please, provide a compilable code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's better to use an abstraction (interface) over a particular implementation. This satisfies most of the contracts. Note that `Collectors.toList()` results in `List<T>` and not `ArrayList<T>` - the return types are incompatible. Start with:

```
public interface EmployeeAudit {
    List<String> fetchEmployeeDetails (double salary);
}
```

Now returning `EmployeeAudit` as a lambda expression. I assume `employeeMap` is `Map<String, Double>` hence you need to map (transform) Stream into the `Map`'s key using `Stream#map(Function)`:

```
public static EmployeeAudit findEmployee() {
    return salary -> employeeMap.entrySet()
                                .stream()
                                .filter(s -> s.getValue() <= salary)
                                .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```